# Place a div on top of a background image element that covers die element when resizing

Tags: html, css, svg

I have my background set to a [svg](/questions/tagged/svg)image. It consists out of a logo and words representing buttons. I integrated the words (Agency Studio Recording Renting) in the image so it resized together with my logo when changing the viewport.

Now I would like to make the button words clickable so I can direct my web visitors to the right department of my website.

My first idea was to make a `div` layer on top of the background image that covers the button words, so that they can be clickable. I used percentages of the viewport for the positioning and the size of the div (the position of the div is absolute) I took this approach so it resizes with the window.

The problem I am facing with this method is that it doesn't follow the words on my background. I guess it's because the background resizes with respect to the ratio of the images and the `div` doesn't.

So how do I make a `div` that follows my button words?

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
  background-color: black;
}

.flex {
  display: -webkit-box;
  /* OLD - iOS 6-, Safari 3.1-6/ Right away we need to weave the old, new, and tweener syntaxes together. Order is important here. Since the display property itself isn't prefixed, we need to make sure we don't override newer syntaxes with older syntaxes for browsers that still (and probably always will) support both.
  .page-wrap { */
  display: -moz-box;
  /* OLD - Firefox 19- (buggy but mostly works) */
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  /* TWEENER - IE 10 */
  display: -webkit-flex;
  /* NEW - Chrome */
  display: flex;
  /* NEW, Spec - Opera 12.1, Firefox 20+ */
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  /*child element alignment not stretched*/
  -moz-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  -justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  /*child element alignment stretched*/
  -moz-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  -align-items: center;
}

.cb-slideshow {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.cb-slideshow li span {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  color: transparent;
  background-size: contain;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  opacity: 0;
  animation: imageAnimation 20s linear infinite 0s;
}

.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(1) span {
  background-image: url(fotos/homepage/CRANKITAGENCY-incl-buttons.svg);
}

.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(2) span {
  background-image: url(fotos/homepage/CRANKITSTUDIO-incl-buttons.svg);
  animation-delay: 5s;
}

.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(3) span {
  background-image: url(fotos/homepage/CRANKITRECORDS-incl-buttons.svg);
  animation-delay: 10s;
}

.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(4) span {
  background-image: url(fotos/homepage/CRANKITRENTING-incl-buttons.svg);
  animation-delay: 15s;
}

@keyframes imageAnimation {
  0% {
    opacity: 0
  }
  5% {
    opacity: 1
  }
  25% {
    opacity: 1
  }
  30% {
    opacity: 0
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0
  }
}

.home-buttons {
  top: 80%;
  left: 8%;
  position: absolute;
  height: 10%;
  width: 84%;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
}

.single-home-button {
  border-right-style: solid;
  border-right-color: white;
  border-right-width: 1xp;
  width: 25%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex home-buttons">
  <div class="single-home-button"></div>
  <div class="single-home-button"></div>
  <div class="single-home-button"></div>
  <div class="single-home-button"></div>
</div>
<ul class="cb-slideshow" style="list-style-type: none">
  <li>
    <span>CrankItAgency</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span>CrankItStudio</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span>CrankItRecords</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span>CrankItRenting</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

[BTW the white boxes, in the image ,represent the nested div I'm creating.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jaAEd.png)

[This is a video link visualising my problem.](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/dbecc4rf7vb1hec/AAA8wLECZAFccf84xZIzgKNRa?dl=0)

Comment: The snippet you've provided doesnt produce the minimum output required to portray the problem. Provide the complete html and css.

Comment: The only thing I should add is the svg file. But I don't know where to put it

Comment: Why don't you load the svg inline and define clicks/links directly on the elements representing the buttons?

Comment: I would not suggest the overlay idea. It will require a lot of testing, and you may end up with a lot of issues when resizing the browser. You said that the background is svg, and the text buttons are parts of it. Why don't you add your events to those svg texts, such that they will be clickable and redirects users accordingly?

Comment: I concur with @ccprog's advive. Either move the buttons out of the background, and live with them possibly moving about a little. Or inline your SVG (ie don't have it as a bg) and make the buttons into links with `<a>` elements. Your current approach is just making things unnecessarily difficult for yourself.